# Display Grid Image & Text Side by Side

Tags: html, css

I want to display Image and text side by side but its being displayed down

[image: Display Image & Text Side By Side]

```
Here is the code pen link https://codepen.io/melwyn-mendonca/pen/RwQPKbp
```

Even on certain screen I want it to be displayed side by side.

What is wring with the CSS?

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to add a `display: flex` property to `grid-item` class in your CSS. Like this:

```
.grid-item {
  /* border-bottom: thin #edf1f2 solid; */
  padding: 22.85px 0px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/suru235/pen/OJQNwwp

Answer (score 0):

How about using a table?

```
<table>
      <tr>
      <td>[image]</td><td>[content]</td>
      <td>[image]</td><td>[content]</td>
      <td>[image]</td><td>[content]</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td>[image]</td><td>[content]</td>
      <td>[image]</td><td>[content]</td>
      <td>[image]</td><td>[content]</td>
      </tr>
      
 </table>
```

You can also put styles inside a table.